# Using anyenv in Fish Shell

Tags: shell, fish

I tried to using [anyenv](https://github.com/riywo/anyenv) in Fish Shell but the error occured.

This is my `~./config/fish/config.fish` file.

```
set -x PATH $HOME/.anyenv/bin $PATH
eval (anyenv init -)
```

What's wrong with this?

Errors which I got:

```
$# is not supported. In fish, please use 'count $argv'.
- (line 1): begin; source "/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/libexec/../completions/anyenv.bash" anyenv() {   typeset command   command="$1"   if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then     shift   fi   command anyenv "$command" "$@" } export NDENV_ROOT="/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv" export PATH="/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/bin:$PATH" export PATH="/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/shims:${PATH}" source "/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/libexec/../completions/ndenv.bash" ndenv rehash 2>/dev/null ndenv() {   typeset command   command="$1"   if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then     shift   fi    case "$command" in   rehash|shell)     eval "`ndenv "sh-$command" "$@"`";;   *)     command ndenv "$command" "$@";;   esac }
                                                                                                                                      ^
from sourcing file -
    called on line 60 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.4.0/share/fish/functions/eval.fish

in function 'eval'
    called on line 6 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish

from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file '-'
```

---

**Added:**

I tried answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119354/7524270) but I get some new errors.

New Errors:

```
Variables cannot be bracketed. In fish, please use "$PATH".
- (line 1): begin; source     "/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/libexec/../completions/anyenv.fish" function anyenv   set command $argv[1]   set -e argv[1]    command anyenv "$command" $argv end set -x NDENV_ROOT "/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv" set -x PATH $PATH "/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/bin" export PATH="/Users/kasumi/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/shims:${PATH}" ndenv rehash 2>/dev/null ndenv() {   typeset command   command="$1"   if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then     shift   fi    case "$command" in   rehash|shell)     eval "`ndenv "sh-$command" "$@"`";;   *)     command ndenv "$command" "$@";;   esac } 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
from sourcing file -
called on line 60 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.5.0/share/fish/functions/eval.fish

in function 'eval'
called on line 4 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish

from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
called during startup

source: Error while reading file '-'
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Quick fix:

In *~/.config/fish/config.fish*, change:

```
eval (anyenv init -)
```

to:

```
eval (anyenv init - fish)
```

***EDIT:*** or a slightly more bullet-proof approach:

```
eval (command anyenv init - fish)
```

(`command` forces `fish` to ignore functions)

#### What's going on?

`anyenv init` uses the `$SHELL` environment variable to determine your active shell and returns some commands, to be executed by the shell, in order to finish the initialization of `anyenv`.

For some reason the `$SHELL` variable in your environment points to `bash` and not to `fish` (you can verify this by running `echo $SHELL`).

The most probable reason is that `fish` is simply not the default shell for your user. You may execute `grep $USER /etc/passwd` to find out (look at what it says after the last `:`). It's possible to change the default shell with `chsh`, but if you decide to do it, do it with great care. There might be some important settings in your `.bashrc` or some other programs may depend on a POSIX-compliant shell to work properly.

Another option is that somewhere you have an override of the `$SHELL` variable, such that it points to `bash` and not `fish`. I have this in my `byobu`/`tmux` configuration because it helped me avoid some strange behavior.

Luckily, `anyenv init` lets the user (you) specify the shell manually (ignore `$SHELL`), and that should fix your issue with `anyenv`.

Comment: Another option, assuming you don't want to change your login shell, is to add `set -x SHELL $__fish_bin_dir/fish` to the top of your ~/.config/fish/config.fish.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
I tried `eval (anyenv init - fish)`
But I get some new errros like my question which I added today.

Is there something missing?

Comment: If your environment is clean, it's a pretty basic setup and there's not much that can go wrong. So my suspicion is that your environment is simply not so clean right now. Namely, I think there are already the remnants of the `bash` flavor `anyenv` function from before. Try to exit `fish` and open it again. Or you can manually erase the `anyenv` function from memory with `functions -e anyenv`, and then retry the init by running `eval (anyenv init - fish)`. Also see the edit to the answer.